# rustc: invalid character `.` in crate name: `rs.tmp`

Tags: rust

Для обучения пишу маленькие программки на расте. Использую
`rustc`, так как не хочу делать целый проект с
`cargo` ради одного маленького бинаря-скрипта. Когда в имени
файла есть точки, получаю такую ошибку:

```sh
$ rustc ./rs.tmp.rs
```

```
error: invalid character `.` in crate name: `rs.tmp`
```

Что можно сделать, не переименовывая файл и не переходя на
`cargo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно задать имя ящика через флаг `--crate-name`:

```sh
$ rustc --crate-name "rstmp" ./rs.tmp.rs
```